# How is it possible for a DIV to display background and text separately on 2 different positions?

Tags: css

**Intro:** I have a `<div>` as block (main) that contains 3 other divs (pieces). I'm giving my divs absolute positions. It worked well first. But then for I don't know what reason the child divs started to display background and text on 2 different positions on the screen:

[image]

**Screenshot:** The red, yellow, blue rects are the "pieces", the main is behind them. The text below "hello world", "random text" etc. should be displayed ontop of the colored backgrounds, since it's just `innerHTML` of each div-piece. Not only that the background AND the area with the text are both receiving mouse events. On the right is the console with some styles of each piece.

**Question:** I need to understand how that would be possible? And what CSS properties cause that? I'm setting all CSS-properties in JavaScript. So there are no style sheets (yet).

```html
<div class="main" style="background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240); color: black; display: block; height: 96px; position: absolute; text-align: left; user-select: none; vertical-align: top; width: 128px; z-index: 1000; left: 127px; top: 302px;">
 <div class="piece" style="background-color: rgb(255, 64, 64); color: black; display: inline-block; height: 32px; position: absolute; text-align: left; user-select: none; vertical-align: top; width: 128px; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 128px; bottom: 32px; line-height: 32;">hello world</div>
 <div class="piece" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 64); color: black; display: inline-block; height: 32px; position: absolute; text-align: left; user-select: none; vertical-align: top; width: 128px; left: 0px; top: 32px; right: 128px; bottom: 64px; line-height: 32;">random text</div>
 <div class="piece" style="background-color: rgb(64, 64, 255); color: black; display: inline-block; height: 32px; position: absolute; text-align: left; user-select: none; vertical-align: top; width: 128px; left: 0px; top: 64px; right: 128px; bottom: 96px; line-height: 32;">goodbye world</div>
</div>
```

I've got the idea that it has something to do with `piece.style.height = 32;` or `piece.style.height = "32px";` That never happened on the horizontal though.

Comment: it's the line-height --> too big so the text is simply overflowing, without unit 32 means 32*font-size

Comment: No. My intention was to make it equal height. To make it possible to middle vertical. I thought that it also meant "pixel".

Comment: so add `px` at the end

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes a simple comment can help fix the whole problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the measurement of the line-height to be the same as your divs. `line-height: 32px` If you do not specify the unit, the browser uses this number (`32`) multiplied by the element's font size (`16px`) = 512px. That's why the text is all down on the page like that.

```html
<div class="main" style="background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240); color: black; display: block; height: 96px; position: absolute; text-align: left; user-select: none; vertical-align: top; width: 128px; z-index: 1000; left: 127px; top: 302px;">
 <div class="piece" style="background-color: rgb(255, 64, 64); color: black; display: inline-block; height: 32px; position: absolute; text-align: left; user-select: none; vertical-align: top; width: 128px; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 128px; bottom: 32px; line-height: 32px;">hello world</div>
 <div class="piece" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 64); color: black; display: inline-block; height: 32px; position: absolute; text-align: left; user-select: none; vertical-align: top; width: 128px; left: 0px; top: 32px; right: 128px; bottom: 64px; line-height: 32px;">random text</div>
 <div class="piece" style="background-color: rgb(64, 64, 255); color: black; display: inline-block; height: 32px; position: absolute; text-align: left; user-select: none; vertical-align: top; width: 128px; left: 0px; top: 64px; right: 128px; bottom: 96px; line-height: 32px;">goodbye world</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the inline CSS `line-height: 32;` causing it. Looks as though the line height is applied to each div but applies to the text within it.

I think line-height is typically applied to e.g. h1, h2, p etc